# How do I can solve this kind of python expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have two expressions like given below:

```
a,b,c=2,4,5

print(a|b*c)
output : 22

How it is returning me the 22
```

and second expression is :

```
print(a|b^c)

output : 3
```

Can anyone please explain to me how python calculating this? I am a newbie in python I don't know how it is calculating this.

Answer (score 1):

**EXPRESSION # 1**

Lets consider,

```
a|b*c
```

[`Precedence`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) of `*` (multiplication) is greater than `|` (bitwise OR) thats why first `b*c` will be computed and then its output will be computed with `a`

STEPS:

1- `b*c` will return 20.

2- Then `a` will perform bit wise OR operation with `b*c`. See [`Bitwise OR operation`](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators) ( OR returns 1 when there is any one else 0)

3- Convert values of `a` and `b*c` to binary and perform bitwise operation. See [`Convert decimal to binary`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-decimal-to-binary)

```
      1 0     > a = 2
1 0 1 0 0     > b*c = 20
_________
1 0 1 1 0     > a|b*c = 22
```

**EXPRESSION # 2**

Lets consider,

```
a|b^c
```

[`Precedence`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) of `^` (bitwise XOR) is greater than `|` (bitwise OR) thats why first `b^c` will be computed and then its output will be computed with `a`

STEPS:

1- Bitwise XOR operation will be performed between b and c (b^c). See [`Bitwise XOR operation`](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators) ( XOR returns 1 when there are odd number of ones else 0)

```
1 0 0   > b = 4
1 0 1   > c = 5
______   
0 0 1   > b^c = 1
```

2- Then `a` will perform bit wise OR operation with `b^c`. See [`Bitwise OR operation`](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators) ( OR returns 1 when there is any one else 0)

```
1 0   > a =2
0 1   > b^c = 1
___
1 1   > a|b^c = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

> print(a|b*c)

Because of the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), the multiplication (`*`) will be processed before the bitwise OR (`|`), so the operations will happen in the following order:

1. `b*c = 4*5 = 20`
2. `a|b*c = 2|20`, i.e `10 OR 10100 = 10110` in binary

That gives us a final answer of `22`.

> print(a|b^c)

Likewise, due to the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), the bitwise XOR (`ˆ`) will be processed first, so we'll have:

1. `bˆc = 4ˆ5`, i.e `100 XOR 101 = 001` in binary
2. `a|bˆc = 2|1`, i.e `10 OR 01 = 11` in binary

That gives us a final answer of `3`.

Answer (score 0):

This is doing a mix of bitwise and integer arithmetic operations.

How does that work?

Based on the order of precedence of operators defined in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), the first expression to be evaluated is b*c, which returns 20. Then we evaluate the expression a|20. This is a bitwise operation on the two integers, so what we are doing is doing a logical OR on each bit of the binary representation of these two numbers i.e. (00010) | (10100) which gives us (10110) i.e. 22

Similarly, in the second example, we first do XOR on b and c, which is equal to 1 (calculated as binary 100 XOR 101 = 001). The result is then bitwise ORed with a, returning the value 3

Comment: can you please explain a lit bit more ?? it is really appreciating

Comment: Do you understand what bitwise operators are?

Answer (score 0):

> The Precedence of arithmetic operators ***, / , +, -** is more than
> bitwise operators **&, |, ^** and both types of operators are evaluated left to right if the same precedence is found.

Moreover,

- for arithmetic operator precedence order is : ***,/ then +,-**
- and for bitwise operator precedence order is: **& , ^,  |**

Check this [article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity) for more information

Coming to the solution:

1. The first expression evaluates like this: a|(b*c)
2. The second expression evaluates like this: a|(b^c)

Answer (score 0):

You need to break down the numbers into their binary representation to see what's happening under the hood.

Case 1,

Binary for a (2) - 00010

Binary for b*c (20) - 10100

So if you do a bitwise OR (|) you'll get a binary sum of above two i.e. 10110 = 22

Case 2,

Binary for a (2) - 00010

Binary for b (4) - 00100

Binary for c (5) - 00101

Again if you do a bitwise XOR (^) you'll get a binary exclusive or of b and c i.e. 00001= 1

Finally if you do a bitwise OR (|) you'll get a binary sum of a with b^c i.e. 00011 = 3